# Object model over database table-functions that abstract the database tables

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to realize an EF model over a set of "virtual tables" that are realized by table-valued functions and stored procedures over the underlying database tables.

The 'virtual tables' are parameterized by a string value, lets call it @mapping. The idea is the @mapping is used by the table-valued functions to map the variants back to various database tables. The virtual tables have associations between them.  The @mapping value is the same for the whole model over the lifetime of the context.

I'm stuck on figuring how to get this to work.
I've specified the EntitySet defining queries as "select * from tvf_myentity('a mapping')", but since it defining queries are not parameterized, I need one ES for each variant.  I then tried using the MEST pattern, but couldn't find an example of how to specify the associations.

So: is there a way of dynamically changing the defining queries before opening the context?
Or is there some other way of approaching this, maybe through the conceptual model?

I also thought of changing the generated code to replace the Navigation properties to call ExecuteStoreQuery instead of using the RelatonshipManager. Is it possible to customize the RelationshipManager?

Answers to the above, or any other idea on how to approach, would be most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: By inserting calls to the TVFs inside the nav properties, I seem to have gotten this to work. EF seems to hook everything up once it is put into the context.